# Eclipse not showing UI properly

Tags: java, eclipse, java-3d

I have transfered my eclipse project from my pc to a laptop. It is a java 3d project, and it should show the main frame with some buttons on the buttonbar at the top, and on the rest of the screen the display of a `SimpleUniverse`
What happens is that all the button stuff is displayed, but not the actual java 3d thing, the usual black of the `SimpleUniverse` and all the interactions supposed to be available are not. Instead, there is just everything gray inside the frame.
  Now the wierd thing comes along. When I do a command from the buttons which modifies in any way the `BranchGroup` atached to the `SimpleUniverse`, everything is back to normal, all functions work.  I think this might be due to the fact that I detach the `BranchGroup`, do the required changes and then attach is back. But still, the question remains.. Why does not is work properly in the first place?

P.S. All the libraries are included and the laptop works better than the PC, has better video card, 1Gb RAM more and a better processor, so I don't think it is a hardware problem

Comment: Is the app. Swing based?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Yes, it is swing based. The weird thing is that on my PC works just after running the app while on the laptop it displays the gray thing until (i guess that's the problem) I reattach the `BranchGroup`. 
The reason I don't think the problem would be the Swing components is simply because they are displayed properly and work properly. The display of `SimpleUniverse` doesn't

Comment: Probably caused by violations of the [EDT rule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) *.."Some Swing component methods are labelled "thread safe" in the API specification; these can be safely invoked from any thread. All other Swing component methods must be invoked from the event dispatch thread. Programs that ignore this rule may function correctly most of the time, but are subject to unpredictable errors that are **difficult to reproduce**."*  Also, in case you missed it - for better help sooner, post an SSCCE.